# eBay API -- any way to retrieve remaining free monthly listings?

Tags: ebay-api

As you are likely aware, eBay offers a quota of free listings, anywhere from 50+ during a calendar month. This is different to one's monthly selling limits, which is specified by the value set by Summary->QuantityLimitRemaining within the GetMyeBaySelling query.

**I'm wondering -- is there any explicit way to retrieve the remaining number of free listings I have left using the eBay API? If not, any suggestions on what might be the best method of calculating it indirectly by using other calls?**

To date, I've been exploring a number of peculiar methods:

-> Using CasperJS to manually log into my account and scrape the content (work in progress, but may ultimately prove the most accurate);

-> Before listing, query the GetAccount for fees and killing the AddItem request if InsertionFees >$0 (works, though lacking in elegance).

Obviously, I could manually count how many listings I have placed on each site e.g. EBAY-US, however, the issue here is that the value of free listings is wildly inconsistent, and may fluctuate with 3-day 200 free listing promotions, etc.

Even if the number of free listings were stable, I would need to be able to account for circumstances where a listing doesn't count towards the free monthly listing e.g. re-listing due to unsuccessful sale.

Moreover, I have found the VerifyAddItem API too unreliable, as it triggers too many false positives, and at times, false negatives.

I must be missing something here -- is there some relevant call I'm simply not aware of?